# Django user roles

Tags: django

I m building a website in which I have 2 types of users.
For each type of user I have a corresponding django application.

I would like when I am logging into the website as type A user or type B user, to be redirected to the appropriate django app and not to be able to access the other application. For logging each user will have a corresponding form.

What is the best approach for this case ?

Comment: how do you plan on choosing a login form before knowing what type of user is logging in? Also, will the two users have anything in common in your app?

Comment: I'll have a main page in which I have a form for user of type A, and a form for user of type B, so you can choose that you login as a user of type A|B.

They'll have basic information in common, but eventually they will diverge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Django Groups Model`, so you gonna create two groups: type A and type B; Each user will be in one of these groups. On your index view, check which group the user belongs to and redirect for whatever you want.

```
def index(request):
   if request.user.groups.filter(name='type A').exists():
     return redirect('/url_type_A/')
   elif request.user.groups.filter(name='type B').exists():
     return redirect('/url_type_B/')
```

Now you can create permission for each group for accessing a certain view or do some specific action. I recommend to create two apps(`python manage.py startapp typeA` and `python manage.py startapp typeB` ) so you can redirect for an entire interface dedicate for the type of user.